# How do I stop Remmina nagging about rdp certficate validation?

Tags: rdp, remmina

I'm RDP-ing to a WIN2K8 machine from Ubuntu 12.04+Remmina but EVERY TIME I'm prompted with a Certificate Validation.

Does anybody knows how to avoid these messages or validate them for good?

.

Answer (score 8):

> Does anybody knows how to avoid these messages

[image]

- Right-click to edit the connection
- Under the "Advanced" tab, set security to either:

  - RDP (less secure, good for local networks)
  - TLS (more secure, better for remote/WAN connections)

Neither of these options will prompt you ever :)

Comment: Ha, ha! Neither of these options will let me connect!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You get this message because the hostname of the certificate does not match the hostname configured in the connection profile in Remmina.
To avoid the certificate validation message you can put the fingerprint of the server-certificate in *~/.freerdp/known_hosts*.

Example: `hostname zb:45:r9:cu8:34:28:z8:69:45:32:19:02:zc:31:4f:b4:p5:34:76`